# Adding Datasource Properties - Tomcat XML

Tags: xml, oracle, tomcat, jdbc

Here's what my code looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hostCon>
  <dataSources>
        <jdbc name="COLL_DB">
        <description>Oracle Database</description>
        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//X.X.X.X:X/X</url>
        <urlProperties>
        <urlProperty>
        <name>restrictGetTables</name>
        <value>true</value>
        </urlProperty>
        </urlProperties>
        <schema>CACS_TPR</schema>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
        </jdbc>
  </dataSources>
</hostCon>
```

How do I add properties like maxactive, maxidle, etc? All the research I've done online show examples but none have quite the same syntax as what I'm working with and none of those examples worked when I tried them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Tomcat, you will need to add it as a new resource.
See a sample where UCP (Universal Connection Pool) is used as a datasource.
You can change the factory and type to use simple OracleDataSource.

```
<Context docBase="UCPTomcat" path="/UCPTomcat"
        reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:UCPTomcat">
<Resource name="tomcat/UCPPool" auth="Container"
            factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl" type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
            description="UCP Pool in Tomcat" connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
            minPoolSize="2" maxPoolSize="60" initialPoolSize="15" autoCommit="true"
            user="scott" password="tiger" fastConnectionFailoverEnabled="true"
            url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=proddb) ))" />

<context-param>
        <param-name>oracle.ucp.PlannedDrainingPeriod</param-name>
        <param-value>30</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>servletUtils.SystemPropertiesHelper</listener-class>    
</listener>
</Context>
```

Comment: Okay, so I've added the Resource to the context.xml. I've also added the resource-ref to the web.xml per the instructions on the site (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html). I'm not sure what to do from here. Do I keep the original jdbc connection string in the hostcon.xml?

Answer (score 0):

After you add it as a resouce, you can invoke this database resource from your servlet as shown below.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext (); 
Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env"); 
// Look up a data source 
javax.sql.DataSource ds= (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup("tomcat/UCPPool"); 
OracleDataSource ods= (OracleDataSource)ds;
```